# Angular 4 ngIf issue

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use *ngIf, but i'm only receiving this error:

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'i'

This is my code:

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="card">

                <div class="card-header bg-info">
                    Pedidos <i  *ngIf="collapse" class="float-right fa fa-caret-up fa-2x"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class='table data-table' id='pedidos'>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `@NgModule(...)` containing this component imports `CommonModule`

```
imports: [CommonModule]
```

otherwise such directives won't be available within that module.

In the `AppModule` importing `BrowserModule` includes already `CommonModule` which makes `ngIf` and others available for components in `AppModule`, but other modules must import their dependencies themselves.